Redisson session management for Spring Webflow
So far we have been running our Spring Webflow based WebApps in a Tomcat cluster with sticky sessions. In the future, Tomcat session management will be implemented using Redisson Session Manager and Redis in order to avoid sticky sessions.
I wonder if this is even possible with Spring Webflow, because this requires the Http sessions to be serialized and synchronized with Redis.
Thanks for your thoughts!
